# Pro Rata Calc - Mid Month Change

Tags: sql

my company has a strange method for calculating pro rata for mid period changes, I was hoping to be able to action this automatically.

Rather than using work days for the whole of the calc the 2nd part of the calc uses working days, the 1st part of the calc uses 21.75 minus the number of working days in the 2nd calc, confused? So am I!

Creating two tables, one for 1st change one for all subsequent changes and then updating based on logic I believe I have this working correctly for the current month, or for a specific month when a date within the month is specified I however need to be able to run this for all months and was hoping an expert may be able to assist.

```
select aa.resource_id, aa.post_id, aa.pro_rata_date, aa.pro_rata_date_to, count(b.trans_date) as working_days, 21.75-count(b.trans_date) as pro_rata_days, row_number() over (partition by aa.resource_id ORDER BY aa.resource_id) as id
from
(select distinct a.resource_id, a.post_id, case when a.date_from > DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))) then a.date_from else DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))) end as pro_rata_date,  case when a.date_to < EOMONTH(getdate()) then a.date_to else EOMONTH(getdate()) end as pro_rata_date_to
from aprresourcepost a
where resource_id IN (select resource_id from aprresourcepost where date_from BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))) and EOMONTH(getdate()))
group by a.resource_id, a.post_id, a.date_from, a.date_to)aa
inner join ahsresschedule b  on aa.resource_id = b.resource_id and aa.post_id = b.post_id and b.trans_date between aa.pro_rata_date and aa.pro_rata_date_to
where b.hrs <>0
group by aa.resource_id, aa.post_id, aa.pro_rata_date, aa.pro_rata_date_to
```

Example; There are 23 working days in July, if I moved roles from role A to role B from the 11th July the pro rata calc would be;

Role A - 6.75 (21.75-Number of working days from Role B)
Role B - 15 (Number of working days)

A change on the 29th July would be

Role A - 18.75 (21.75-Number of working days from Role B)
Role B - 3 (Number of working days).

Comment: I guess 21.75 is approximately the average number of working days in a month, so the algorithm kind of makes sense. Note that "pro rata" means proportion, and you aren't calculating proportion at all - just the difference between 21.75 and some number. Having said that, I don't understand what the question is. Obviously `21.75 - x` is straightforward - are you asking how to count the number of 'working days' (weekdays?) from a specific date till the end of the given month?

Comment: Thanks for replying, Yes you're right 21.75 equates to 261 working days, just wish they would use actual working days which would be more accurate and a lot easier! The pro rata takes place after the days have been calculated so you're correct this is providing the figures for the proportioning to take place. Basically any mid period change that doesn't start on the 1st of the month needs to be identified and the number of working days retrieved, in the example where resource in does this, I want to try and do this for all time. Do you think its worth re-doing this to make this clear?